# Mocking dependencies with Vitest

Tags: node.js, mocking, vitest

The following code https://i.stack.imgur.com/vs7vp.png works when I use Jest, but it doesn't work with Vitest.

I understand that Vitest operates differently in this scenario, but I haven't been able to find a solution yet.

Has anyone tried to mock a dependency using Vitest before?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How AwsS3Adapter is exported from module?

Comment: export class AwsS3Adapter...

Comment: Could you add the code in the question instead of the link to the image?

Answer (score 0):

I have this line at the beginning of the file:

```
vi.mock('@infra/storage/s3-adapter/aws-s3.adapter');
```

I could only solve this by adding "await import(..." and the mocking operations inside the "it" block like this:

```
it('should returns 200 and the document added to the program', async () => {
  // Arrange
  const awsS3Adapter = await import(
    '@infra/gateways/storage/aws-s3.adapter'
  );

  awsS3Adapter.AwsS3Adapter.prototype.uploadFile = vi
    .fn()
    .mockResolvedValue('any_file_path');

  awsS3Adapter.AwsS3Adapter.prototype.getUrl = vi
    .fn()
    .mockResolvedValue(`any_url`);
```

If I try to use it in a `beforeAll` or outside the "it" it doesn't work. So, I need to repeat this code in each block every time I need to mock the Adapter.